# Tor completely broken on Windows 10 after upgrade

Tags: windows

Tor has been working fine for ages, but after prompting to upgrade itself can no longer start, constantly saying that it had 'unexpectedly exited'. I looked here and the advice was to delete the folder but that's proved impossible, with many files locked, and trying to copy the log file produced a blank document.

Again, I looked here and the other advice was to reinstall, so I tried that but once again got errors

> error opening file for writing: `Tor\libevent-2-0-5.dll`

So I'm totally stuck. I've got bits of the first installation that can't be deleted and half a reinstall. Help!

Comment: Does the file `Tor\libevent-2-0-5.dll` exist? What permissions does it have? Please try to download and install Tor Browser into a new and empty directory. Can you start this without problems?

Comment: for **writing** ??

Comment: What exactly your install is? I'll be able to help if I'll know more about what it is and how it worked/supposed to work

Comment: Tor install 5.5.3_en-US. I tried installing into two separate directories and both times when I try to start the program I get the same error in two pop up windows.:
"Tor unexpectedly exited. This mght be due to a bug with Tor itself.. etc"

Clicking the 'Retart Tor' button just brings the same thing again and again.

Comment: Clicking on 'Copy Tor Log To Clipboard' produces no text at all...

Comment: libevent-2-0-5.dll has all permissions ticked

Comment: Try cmd, type caps IPCONFIG /DNSFLUSH
i am sure it will work

Comment: can you explain *why* the DNS cache would cause it to have problems opening a file? especially since Tor Browser doesn't use local DNS at all.